# Is there any other way to enable the shell_exec command in web without threat the security?

Tags: php, hosting, shell-exec

I have an application with the `shell_exec` command in the script. It's impossible to host because of the security reason when I use that script it will affect the server. Is there any other way to still use the `shell_exec` command without threat to the server?

Answer (score 1):

shell_exec is meant to be run on the server.  So to answer your question, no.  Unless your host provides you with command line access.  Then PHP can utilize it.

Comment: is there any web hosting that provides the command line access? Thank You.

Comment: Sure, VPS, dedicated, and most cloud hosting (which is usually just a VPS) lets you do it.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Is VPS free or not? Can you tell me a simple description about VPS?

Comment: You're very unlikely to find any free hosts offering this.

Comment: VPS stands for virtual private server.  It means you have your own area on a server.  It is not free.

Comment: @dinda If this information helped you, please accept the answer!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Micro Instance on Amazon
http://aws.amazon.com/free/
but it's unlikely for beginner

Comment: This does not answer the question.